# MySQL subquery really slow... Workaround?

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery

I've tested the following seemingly simple query on MySQL 5.0, 5.1, 5.5 and found it to be extremely slow.

```
select * from entry where session_id in
    (select session_id from entry where created_at > [some timestamp])
```

Multiple entry's can have the same session ID, but different created_at timestamps.
The query is meant to grab all entry's that have at least one entry from the same session_id whose created_at is greater than the specified timestamp.

I've seen others speak of MySQL subquery performance issues with similar queries, and that MySQL considers the subquery a dependent query and it is doing a full table scan on the outer query.  Suggested workarounds were something like:

```
select * from entry where session_id in
    (select session_id from
        (select session_id from entry where created_at > [some timestamp])
    as temp)
```

However, this hack doesn't work for me and makes it even slower.

Any ideas on how to rewrite this query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on your data distribution, use this

```
SELECT  e.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  session_id, MAX(created_at)
        FROM    entry
        GROUP BY
                session_id
        HAVING  MAX(created_at) > $mytimestamp
        ) ed
JOIN    entry e
ON      e.session_id = ed.session_id
```

(create an index on `(session_id, created_at)`), or this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT e.*
FROM    entry ed
JOIN    entry e
ON      e.session_id = ed.session_id
WHERE   ed.created_at > $mytimestamp
```

(create two separate indexes on `created_at` and `session_id`)

Comment: You da man.  Thanks!
I started off with something like the 2nd query, but left out distinct.  I didn't know you can apply distinct to a whole result set with a wildcard.  Awesome.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a problem with the double subquery trick too,
btw I just found out that using this worked for me (based on your query):

```
select * from entry where session_id in
    (select (select session_id from entry where created_at > [some timestamp]))
```

In my case the original query could work for hours using a join or the "normal" double subquery trick, with the modified double subquery it took 0 secs :)

Comment: this is very useful because very easy to apply! However it's strange this behavior of MySQL...

Comment: This works only in case if the inner query returns a single result. Otherwise you'll get the error "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: Replying to the last comment, the double subquery will work for more than one result so long as it is (SELECT * FROM (select session_id from entry etc) )

Mysql still has a problem with these types of queries and requires a bit of finagling to get the optimizer to choose the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e2.*
    FROM entry e1
        INNER JOIN entry e2
            ON e1.session_id = e2.session_id
    WHERE e1.created_at > [some timestamp]
```

If you don't already have them, indexes on `created_at` and `session_id` would probably be helpful as well.

Comment: you would also need `group by e2.id` or you will get duplicates.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I initially tried, actually.  This was giving me duplicates.  Didn't occur to me to use group by.  Or you can use distinct e2.*.